# How to explicitly free EADDRINUSE port for binding it again?

Tags: linux, networking, sockets

```
$ testOnDemandRTSPServer
... Play this stream using the URL "rtsp://192.168.90.2:8554 ...
^C
$ testOnDemandRTSPServer
Failed to create RTSP server: bind() error (port number: 8554): Address already in use
```

How to manually explicitly free up the port after a non-REUSEADDR program?

I don't want to wait or change port every time...

Comment: Link: http://serverfault.com/questions/329845/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, on Linux there's nothing you can do (other than fixing the code to set `SO_REUSEADDR`). From `man 7 socket`:

```
Linux will only allow port reuse with the SO_REUSEADDR option when this
option was set both in the previous program that performed a bind(2) to
the port and in the program that wants to reuse the port. This differs
from some implementations (e.g., FreeBSD) where only the later program
needs to set the SO_REUSEADDR option. Typically this difference is invisible,
since, for example, a server program is designed to always set this option.
```

Comment: Is it just me who annoyed by `Address already in use` message during development? Maybe somebody hacked up a kernel module that just flushes all TIME_WAIT sockets?